# Symfony2 count how many route we have

Tags: symfony

Is there a way we count how many route we have on Symfony2?
I can get list of route available in production environment with this console command:

`$ app/console router:debug -e prod`

But i want to count it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just leverage that command and use `wc` to count the routes

```
// Count the number of routes in the system
// Subtract the number of header lines (2) from the result
$numRoutes = (int) `php app/console router:debug -e prod | wc -l` - 2;
```

It's a bit clunky but it works. You could be a bit more sophisticated and put this into a Command of your own if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

An approach would be to use the router service.
If you are using this inside a controller you can get the count with:

```
$routesCount = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->count()
```

But if you want the count in another place, you should use the service container (that is what the controller do for you).
See the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) if you are new to the Symfony service container or want to lear more about this feature.